# How to navigate to a page in project2 on the same server from project1?

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, server

I have Two project I put it in remote server AWS

1. the **project1** is the landing page and the path on server is `/var/www/html/project1`
2. the **project2** is the laravel project with vuejs and the dashboard on it and the pth on remote server is : `/var/www/html/project2`

The question is :

When the client type in the url `www.example.com`, then the **project1** is open (landing page). Then when he clicks on, for example, the login page, he navigates to **project2**, because the login page found in **project2** (laravel project)

how can I do this?

and thanks :))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N0yo.png)

Comment: If the `project1` is just 1 landing page you might as well incorporate it into your laravel project. If not, there's various things you can do. Each page must have a different url. You can even have 2 projects on the same domain but just make sure the urls are properly separated.

Comment: can you please explain more to me because I am useing in project two (vuejs front end) and in project one make it by (html +css)